# Strategies for bounding the spectral norm of a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory, hypergraph, multilinear-algebra, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a symmetric $k$-tensor over a real or complex vector field $W$. We may define its *spectral norm* $|A|$ by
$$|A| = \sup_{v\in W} \frac{|\langle A,x^{\otimes k}\rangle|}{|x|_2^k}.$$
(Alternatively, we may define it in a different, standard way and then show that the above inequality holds - that is a theorem of Banach's (see, e.g., [https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/work/nuclear.pdf](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/work/nuclear.pdf) , beginning of section 5).)

What would be some strategies -- combinatorial of preference -- to bound the norm of $|A|$? By "combinatorial" I mean something analogous to "counting paths".

---

Let me give an example of a common strategy for $k=2$. The trace of any power $A^m$ of a real symmetric matrix can be expressed in two ways: combinatorially, that is, as a sum over closed paths (interpreting $A$ as the adjacency matrix of a graph with weights) and spectrally, as a sum $\sum_i \lambda_i^m$ over all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. In fact, we do not need the full spectral decomposition - it is enough to note that $\langle v,A^2 v\rangle = \langle A v,A v\rangle \geq 0$ for any $v$. Then it follows that, for $m$ even,
$$|A|^m\leq \textrm{Tr}\,A^m = (\text{sum over closed paths}).$$
There are various ways to amplify this bound (e.g., high multiplicity).

Is an inequality even vaguely resembling this one possible for higher $k$?

Comment: It depends on what quality of bound you want. You can take the sum $\langle A, x^{\otimes k} \rangle$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz a bunch to bound it in terms of the $2$-norm of $x$ and some kind of sum-of-product invariants of $A$. The simplest case of this is, for a three-tensor, to observe $ |A_{ijk} x_i x_j x_k|^2\leq |x|_2^2 | \sum_{ijlm} x_i x_j x_l x_m \sum_{k} A_{ijk} A_{lmk}| $ and then estimate the spectral norm of $\sum_{k} A_{ijk} A_{lmk}$ as an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix with coordinates $(i,l)$ and $(j,m)$.

Comment: However, doing so will not get you bounds for $\langle A, x^{\otimes k} \rangle$ that are as strong as those known for a random tensor (which you can do for matrices, of course). But this may be a reflection of the strength of bounds provable for random tensors more than the weakness of these methods (which I learned about from Tao's paper "Expanding polynomials over finite fields of large characteristic, and a regularity lemma for definable sets
" https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2894 building on Bukh and Tsimerman's "Sum-product estimates for rational functions")

Comment: Hm, those bounds do seem to be insufficient in the situation I had in mind (fairly sparse tensor).

Comment: For an $n\times n \times n$ tensor, I think the cutoff should be $n^{3/2+\epsilon}$ nonvanishing entries, which makes the $n^2\times n^2$ matrix have at least $n^{2+\epsilon}$ entries nonvanishing. Your tensor has fewer than that?

Comment: Yes. I am interested in the "adjacency tensor" (so to speak) of a hypergraph of relatively low degree.

Comment: Perhaps one can rigorously prove a no-go argument that approaches based on sums over higher-dimensional paths won't work. The idea being that if some polynomial function of the matrices of $A$ bounds the spectral norm, then presumably its average under $O(n)$ does as well, so we can assume it is $O(n)$-invariant. We can classify the $O(n)$-invariant polynomials and show that they all look roughly like the traces of powers of the matrix I wrote there, and for a typical low-degree tensor they are dominated by a trivial diagonal regardless of if the tensor is random or highly structured.

Comment: The only result I know for an explicit tensor sparser than the square-root barrier is "On the polynomial Szemeredi theorem over finite fields" by Peluse (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.02200.pdf), which is about an $n\times n \times \dots n $ $k$-tensor supported on a set of size $n^2$. This is sub-sqrt for $k>4$ but still probably larger than what you want, and the argument very much takes advantage of the additive structure and low-degree polynomial structure. I am no expert but I think this is the level of techniques that would be needed for similar problems...

Comment: Peluse's paper is not stated in terms of tensors - care to indicate how the rephrasing goes?

Comment: In a vector space with a basis $e_{a}$ corresponding to the elements $x\in \mathbb F_q$, we have an $m+1$-tensor $ B= \sum_{x,y\in \mathbb F_q} e_{x} \otimes e_{ x+P_1(y)} \otimes \dots \otimes e_{ x+ P_m(y)}$, and once we subtract off the "trivial eigenvalue" by taking $A = B - p^{1-m} \sum_{x_0,\dots, x_m \in \mathbb F_q} e_{x_0} \otimes e_{x_1} \otimes \dots \otimes e_{a_m}$, her result is equivalent to a bound for $\langle A, v^{\otimes k} \rangle/ |v|_{\infty}^k$, which is what you wrote down except for the $\ell^\infty$ norm instead of the $\ell^2$.

Comment: The $v$ here corresponds to $f_0,\dots, f_m$ in her paper. If subtracting off the trivial eigenvalue makes it no longer sufficiently sparse, you could replace $e_x \otimes$ by $\chi(x)$ for $\chi$ a quadratic character to get a tensor which needs no subtraction.

Comment: I guess that what I am looking for is an argument that allows one to go from (say) an $n\times n\times n\times n$ $4$-tensor (say) supported on a set of size $m n$ to an $n^{\otimes^{4 r}}$ $4r$-tensor supported on a set of size about $m^r n$. Taking $r>(\log n)/\log m$ (or, even better, $r>3 (\log n)/\log m$), one could then perhaps get somewhere.

Comment: (Your sketch of a no-go argument is interesting - care to flesh it out? Does it show that the kind of argument I just said I am looking for cannot work?)

Comment: If you replace $|x|_{2}^{k}$ in the denominator by $|x|^{k}_{\infty}$ then there are lower bounds of this "spectral norm" in terms of $\ell^{\frac{2k}{k+1}}$ norm of $\{A_{i_{1}, .., i_{k}}\}$ and a constant $C=C(k)$. Bohnenblust--Hille, and Littlewood's 4/3  inequality are good keywords.  I have not seen "counting paths" in the proofs of  lower bounds. The proofs use hypercontractivity, and certain Blei's type inequalities, and  perhaps Blei's inequality is the one which should count as "combinatorial part".  See around page 8, https://analytic.wmi.amu.edu.pl/static/slides/Defant.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will show, with some non-rigorous steps, that a bound of this form that is valid for arbitrary tensors and useful for sparse tensors (fewer than $n^{k/2}$ nonvanishing entries) does not exist.

First note that there is a problem with using the $\ell^2$ norm to define the spectral norm for very sparse tensors $A$, regardless of how you try to bound it. The reason is that, assuming the nonzero entries of $A$ are normalized to have size $\approx 1$, the minimum value you could possibly hope to bound the spectral norm to is $\approx 1$, by choosing some nonzero entry $A_{n_1n_2 \dots n_k}$ of $A$ and choosing $x$ a sparse vector supported on $n_1,\dots, n_k$.

This means if $x$ is a vector of support of size $m$ and average size $1$, then the $\ell^2$ norm of $x$ is $m^{1/2}$, so the best bound you could hope for on $\langle A, x^{\otimes k} \rangle$ from the spectral norm is $m^{k/2}$. But the trivial bound for $\langle A, x^{\otimes k} \rangle$ is $md$ where $d$ is the maximum degree of $A$ (the maximum number of nonzero entries in a hyperplane slice of $A$). So to get a nontrivial bound you want $m < d^{ \frac{2}{k-2}}$, which is pretty small if $d$ is large!

So I'll use the $\ell^p$ norm instead for the remainder, for some $p\geq k$.

Let $W = \mathbb R^n$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$. Suppose that $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial in the entries of a tensor $A$ in $W^{ \otimes k}$ where we have an inequality of the form
$$ \left(\sup \frac{ \langle A, x^{\otimes k} \rangle}{ |x|_p^k} \right)^{d} \leq f(A) $$

(One could think we should allow absolute values on the right side but we can just square both sides to remove them.)

I will argue rigorously that the coefficient of some monomial in $f$ has size at least $n^{ dk (1/2-1/p)}/ O_{d,k}(1)$ and heuristically that no $f$ with such a large coefficient gives a good bound for highly sparse tensors.

Translating $f$ by any matrix $g$ in the group $  (\mathbb Z/2) \rtimes S_n$ produces a tensor with the same spectral norm. So the minimum of $f( g\cdot A)$ for $g \in (\mathbb Z/2) \rtimes S_n$ for also bounds the spectral norm. It follows that the average of $f(g\cdot A)$ over $g \in (\mathbb Z/2) \rtimes S_n$ also bounds the spectral norm. This average cannot increase the largest coefficient of a monomial in $f$, so we may as well assume $f$ is $(\mathbb Z/2) \rtimes S_n$-invariant.

By scaling, certainly $f$ must be homogeneous of degree $d$.

We can write $f$ as a sum over monomials of the form $\prod_{i=1}^d A_{a_{i,1} \dots a_{i,k}}$ for some tuple $a_{i,j}$ of numbers from $1$ to $n$ indexed by $i$ from $1$ to $d$ and $j$ from $1$ to $k$.

The $(\mathbb Z/2)^n$-invariance implies the coefficient of a monomial vanishes if any number appears an odd number of times among the $a_{i,j}$.  The $S_n$-invariance says the coefficients of a monomial depend only on the choice of $a_{i,j}$ up to permutation. We can express this as the claim that $f$ is a linear combination of the polynomials of the form

$$ \sum_{ a \colon [m] \to [n] \textrm{ injective}} \prod_{i=1}^d A_{ a (l_{i,1}) a(l_{i,2}) \dots a(l_{i,j})}$$ for some fixed tuple $l_{i,j}$ of integers from $1$ to $m$ indexed by $i$ from $1$ to $d$ and $j$ from $1$ to $k$, where each number appears an even number of times among the $l_{i,j}$ (which we may assume is at least twice). The sum is over injective maps from the numbers $1$ to $m$ to the numbers $1$ to $n$. We could, if we chose, drop the "injective" condition.

Now let's consider what happens when we apply this inequality to the all-$1$s tensor. This tensor has spectral norm $\frac{n^k}{ n^{ k/p}}$, so the left side is $n^{d k (1-1/p)}$.

The value of the invariant polynomial $\sum_{ a \colon [m] \to [n] \textrm{ injective}} \prod_{i=1}^d A_{ a (l_{i,1}) a(l_{i,2}) \dots a(l_{i,j})} $ is just the number of injective maps from $[m]$ to $n$, which is at most $n^m$.

Because each $\ell$ occurs at least twice among the $\ell_{i,j}$, we have $m \leq d k / 2$.

Thus the sum of the coefficients of these various polynomials in the linear expression for $f$ must be at least $n^{ d k (1/2-1/p)}$. Since the number of different polynomials that can appear depends only on $d$ and $k$, the coefficient of one of the monomials must be at least $n^{ d k (1/2-1/p)}/ (dk)^{dk}$.

---

Now consider a sparse tensor $A$, say with $N$ nonvanishing entries, each of size $1$. Assuming $A$ comes from some tricky mathematical construction, we are unlikely to get an estimate for $f(A)$ with error term smaller than the largest coefficient of a monomial in $f$ as that would require getting an estimate for a difficult sum with error term less than a single term of the sum.

Thus, we won't expect to get a bound for the spectral norm of $A$ better than $n^{  k (1/2-1/p)}/ (dk)^k \approx n^{ k(1/2-1/p)}$ (assuming $d,k$ grow slowly, which is reasonable).

If we plug a "typical" vector $x$ into $A$, whose entries have size around $1$, we will therefore not get a bound for $\langle A, x^{\otimes k} \rangle$ better than $n^{ k /2}$. But if $N < n^{k/2}$, this is worse than the trivial bound for the sum, so our spectral norm estimate will be useless for such vectors.

---

One can actually construct an explicit polynomial bound for the spectral norm where the coefficients of the monomials have size $\approx n^{1/2 - 1/p}$ by proving a bound for the $\ell^2$-spectral norm using Cauchy-Schwarz a bunch and then bounding the $\ell^2$ norm trivially via the $\ell^p$ norm.

For $p<1/2$, the lower bound is instead $1$, which I think you can also achieve by using Holder's inequality repeatedly.

An example of the Cauchy-Schwarz argument, for an $n \times n \times n$ tensor:

We have

$$ \left(\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3 \in [n]} A_{i_1i_2i_3} x_{i_1} x_{i_2} x_{i_3}\right)^8 \leq |x|_2^8  \left( \sum_{i_1 \in [n]} \left( \sum_{i_2, i_3 \in [n]} A_{i_1 i_2 i_3} x_{i_2} x_{i_3} \right)^2 \right)^4 =  |x|_2^8  \left( \sum_{i_1 ,i_2 ,i_3,i_4,i_5\in [n]}  A_{i_1 i_2 i_3} A_{i_1 i_4 i_5} x_{i_2} x_{i_3} x_{i_4} x_{i_5}  \right)^4 \leq |x|_2^{16} \left( \sum_{i_2, i_4\in [n]} \left( \sum_{i_1,i_3,i_5\in [n]} A_{i_1 i_2 i_3} A_{i_1 i_4 i_5} x_{i_3} x_{i_5} \right)^2 \right)^2  =|x|_2^{16} \left(\sum_{ i_1, i_2, i_3,i_4, i_5, i_6, i_7, i_8 \in [n]} A_{i_1 i_2 i_3} A_{i_1 i_4 i_5} A_{i_6 i_2 i_7} A_{i_6 i_4 i_8} x_{i_3} x_{i_5} x_{i_7} x_{i_8} \right)^2  \leq |x|_2^{24}  \sum_{i_3, i_5 ,i_7, i_8 \in [n ] } \left( \sum_{i_1, i_2, i_4, i_6 \in [n]}  A_{i_1 i_2 i_3} A_{i_1 i_4 i_5} A_{i_6 i_2 i_7} A_{i_6 i_4 i_8}  \right)^2$$

which, when you expand it out, should have an elegant symmetric structure where the eight copies of $A$ correspond to the vertices of the cube and the various $i$ indices to edges.

Comment: To whom is this remarkable classification of the O(W)-invariant functions due?  I'd never seen this before.

Comment: @JSE From a paper of Deligne, it looks like the original reference may be H. Weyl, Classical Groups, their Invariants and Representations. It is (not always) called "the first fundamental theorem of invariant theory for the orthogonal group".

Comment: @WillSawin I agree that using the $\ell^k$ norm would make more sense than using the $\ell^2$ norm. But do we have an analogue of the inequality of Banach's alluded to above in that case?

Comment: @HAHelfgott I believe so. We have some identity like $k! \langle A , x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes \dots x_k \rangle = \sum_{ S \subseteq 1,\dots, k} (-1)^{k-|S|} \langle A, (\sum_{i\in S} x_i)^{\otimes k} \rangle $ and then we can bound the right side in terms of  $\sum_{ S \subseteq 1,\dots, k} |\sum_{i\in S} x_i|_k^k$ which after rescaling $x_1,\dots, x_k$ to have the same norm is a constant factor times $|x_1|_k|x_2|_k \dots |x_k|_k$

Comment: Well, the constant factor here is in the scale of $k^k$, so one has to be a little careful.

Comment: @HAHelfgott I don't dispute this (except the k! on the left helps so maybe it's only exponential in $k$).

Comment: I still can't say I understand the classification of O(W)-invariant functions (due to Deligne or Weyl) that you just gave. First, I don't see why the functions given here are $O(W)$-invariant, as opposed to just $S_n$-invariant. Second, given a polynomial, how do we determine $k$?

Comment: @HAHelfgott An alternate description that makes the $O(W)$ invariance more clear. Given a tensor in $W^{ \otimes k}$, tensor it with itself  to get a tensor in $W^{\otimes (k \times |V(G)| } $ then apply the bilinear $W \otimes W \to \mathbb R$ a total of $k \times |V(G)|/2$ times, each time collapsing two of the factors of $W$. This is $O(W)$-invariant because the  bilinear form is $O(W)$-invariant. What $k$ is will be obvious since it's a polynomial function on $W^{\otimes k}$ or, concretely a sum of products of terms of the form $A_{i_1i_2\dots i_k}$.

Comment: Just for clarity the "trace of an $n$th power of $A$" polynomial function on a 2-tensor / matrix $A$ is coming from a $2$-regular graph $G$, i.e., an $n$-cycle. Then $k$-regular graphs give polynomial functions on $k$-tensors in the same way, and the proof of $O(W)$-invariance is morally sort of the same.

Comment: @WillSawin In the end, the argument above indicates that there shouldn't be a polynomial bound for the spectral norm that is tight for sparse tensors, assuming that our intuition that having our hyperedges have random signs decrases the norm is correct. But is it? Also, what would be a good reason for the fact that there are good bounds for $k=2$ (just choose a large enough power $m$ in $\tr A^m$) but,  it would seem, not for general $k$?

Comment: @HAHelfgott The argument I know that bounds the norm of a randomly signed tensor in the non-sparse, $\ell^2$ case involves first checking that for any particular vector the probability that $\langle A, x^{\otimes k} \rangle$ is large for randomly signed $A$ is very small, showing that to bound the spectral norm it suffices to check this for boundedly many $x$ (forming an $\epsilon$-net in the unit sphere), and using the union bound.

Comment: There is an obvious analogue of this for sparse tensors and using an $\ell^k$-sphere - the question is whether the relevant net has too many points compared to the number of sign arrangements. I haven't checked this, but I hope there is some sparse range where the argument can be made to work, although I'm now not confident it will work all the way down to your highly-sparse range.  But there may be other ways to show that polynomial invariants are problematic here. (to be continued...)

Comment: @HAHelfgott One simple modification is to start with a tensor which is assumed to have small spectral norm and try to sign it to make the spectral norm larger (say, make every entry positive). But then one has to argue why the "off-diagonal" terms really do give a lesser contribution, since the associated graph is not necessarily an expander.  // For a "good reason", you can actually see a version of the phenomenon for $k=1$. Suppose we want to bound $\sup \langle v, w\rangle / |v|_q$ in terms of polynomial invariants of $w$.

Comment: We clearly need to bound the $\ell^p$ norm of $w$. But the $\ell^p$ norm of $w$ is only a polynomial for $p$ an even integer, so by Holder's inequality we can only handle the cases $q = 2r/(2r-1)$ for integer $r$ without getting a bound that's suboptimal, and $q \leq 2$ without getting a bound that's off by a power of $n$. I think this continues in higher tensors - polynomial invariants of multilinear norms always behave like at least $2$-norms, hence they only have reasonable inequalities vs. vector norms that are at most $2$-norms, but for sparseness reasons you need at least $k$-norms.

Comment: @WillSawin Well, but even in the case $k=2$, we do not really have a good polynomial bound on the norm; rather, we have a good polynomial bound on a high power of the norm. Does that get around your objection? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @HAHelfgott It doesn't get around - even in $k=1$ I should have said "a power of the $\ell^p$ norm of $w$ is only a polynomial for $p$ an even integer".

Comment: @HAHelfgott  If we want to bound a power of $\sup \langle A, x^k \rangle / |x|^q$ by a polynomial in $A$, for $q=2r/(r-1)$, $A$ an integer, we can do this with sums of the form $\sum_{a_1,\dots, a_N =1}^n  \prod_{j=1}^m A_{a_{i_{j,1}} a_{i_{j,2}} \dots a_{i_{j,k}}}$ where $i_{j,l}$ is a fixed array of numbers from $1$ to $N$, with $j$ ranging from $1$ to $m$ and $l$ ranging from $1$ to $k$, in which each number appears $2r$ times. So it seems to get other values of $q$ we need other values of $r$, in particular $<1$, but this is impossible.

Comment: @WillSawin I am not sure I understand. Say I am trying to bound $\langle A,x^{\otimes k}\rangle/|x|_k^k$. Then I can see that I would need my polynomial bound to be linear on the entries of $A$, and it shouldn't be hard to show that that won't work out for $k>2$. But why couldn't there be a bound on $(\langle A,x^{\otimes k}\rangle/|x|_k^k)^{\ell}$ for some large $\ell$ given by a polynomial of degree $\ell$ on the entries of $A$?

Comment: @HAHelfgott Edited to give a more rigorous argument - the key point is that if you prove a bound valid for general tensors, it must apply to, for example, the all $1$s tensor, which force your polynomial to have big coefficients in front of the monomials, which then make it hard to give a more precise bound.

Comment: @WillSawin: It is hard to trace the FFT for $O(W)$ but it is certainly not due to Weyl. One can find it the 1897 article by Eduard Study in the Leipzig Berichte https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101078345459&view=1up&seq=451

Comment: @WillSawin I think you mean $p$ when you write $q$ in the edited version.

Comment: @HAHelfgott Or did I mean $q$ when I wrote $p$? It's a philosophical question.

Comment: @WillSawin Actually, how exactly do you bound the $\ell^2$ spectral norm by using Cauchy-Schwarz a bunch?

Comment: @HAHelfgott I edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: Incidentally, the final expression in this new example is (the eighth power of what is known as) the Gowers box norm of the tensor $A$, which is indeed a good tool for understanding the spectral norm of $A$ (and more) when $A$ is dense, but not when $A$ is sparse.